# Windows Server 2008 R2 deathly slow in ESX 3.0.2

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esx

Can anyone suggest some tuning tips for running 2 small (1CPU,3GB RAM) Windows Server 2008 R2 VMs within ESX 3.0? The VMware tools install just fine, save the SVGA driver. I suspect that is the problem with the horrid RDP performance.

Comment: That is seriously old code. Time to upgrade, I think.

Comment: upgraded to vSphere. everything is working wonderfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a display driver issue which is resolved in ESX(i) 4.0 Update 1. So, **update**.

Vmware used VMware SVGA-II (before 4.0.1), this is what is causing this issue with Win 7 and Win 2008. After 4.0.1, they started using VMware SVGA 3D (WDDM), which solved the problem.

Comment: Yes..  I think that is the only safe path.